# Tabbing to textbox on row selected in pure XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on some XAML/WPF where we create a template of the form that then get compiled into a dll and this dll is then used by a blackbox application to render the form to the user.

Ideally, I should be able to this entirely in XAML, but I am not fully aware of what can and cannot be done in XAML.

I have the following:

```
<cad:SortableListView.View>
    <GridView DataGridRow.Selected="">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Message #" cad:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="MessageId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MessageId}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Critical" cad:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Message.IsReceiptRequested" CellTemplate="{StaticResource criticalCellTemplate}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Date/Time" cad:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Message.SendingTime" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message.SendingTime.LocalDateTime, StringFormat={}{0:G}}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" cad:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Message.Subject" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message.Subject}"  Width="140"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="From Terminal" cad:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Message.SendingTerminal" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message.SendingTerminal}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Sender" cad:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Message.SendingEmployeeId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message.SendingEmployeeId}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Priority" cad:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Message.Priority" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message.Priority}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Event" cad:SortableListView.SortPropertyName="Message.LocalEvent.AgencyEventId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message.LocalEvent.AgencyEventId}"/>
    </GridView>
</cad:SortableListView.View>
....
More code
....
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,5">
    Reply:
</TextBlock>
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ReplyText}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="10,0,30,5"/>
<Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,30,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    Command="{Binding Path=Acknowledge.Command}"
    cad:CreateCommandBinding.Command="{Binding Path=Acknowledge}" IsDefault="True">
    Acknowledge
</Button>
```

I need it so that when a row is selected from the grid, the cursor has to jump to the text box and when "Enter" is pressed, the button click event is fired.  I *think* I managed to do that by setting it as the default (IsDefault = "true").  Its the only button on the screen so I'm not too worried about something else firing.

Again, the ideal is to be able to do this in pure XAML, but if a file needs to be attached, kindly show me how to reference this code behind file.

Thank you